# Why will the following code not compile (inheritance in c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

So this is not about a problem I faced but about a question in an exam I am not able to answer properly.

I have the following class:

```
template<class T>
class Server {
protected:
  std::vector<T> requests;
public:
 Server() = default;
 Server(const Server& other) = default;
 ~Server() = default;
 Server(const std::vector<T>& vec);
 Server& operator=(const Server<T>& other) = default;
 Server& operator+=(const T& request);
 Server& operator-=(const T& request);
 void operator()();
 std::size_t numRequests() const;
 friend Server<T> operator+(const Server<T>& a, const Server<T>& b );
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Server<T>&);
};
template<class T>
Server<T> operator+(const Server<T>& a, const Server<T>& b );
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Server<T>&);
```

Now, I create a class named `LimitedNamedServer`, the difference between the classes are that `LimitedNamedServer`objects has a maximum capacity of requests and a name.

This is what it looks like:

```
template<class T>
LimitedNamedServer : public Server<T> {
 std::string name;
 std::size_t maxLimit;
public:
 LimitedNamedServer(const char* name, std::size_t limit) : Server<T>(), name(name), maxLimit(limit) {}
 LimitedNamedServer(const LimitedNamedServer& other) = default;
 ~LimitedNamedServer() = default;
 LimitedNamedServer(const char* name, std::size_t limit, const std::vector<T>& vec) : Server<T>(vec), name(name), maxLimit(limit) {
if(requests.size() > maxLimit) {
throw OverLimit();
 }
}
 LimitedNamedServer& operator=(const LimitedNamedServer<T>& other) = default;
 LimitedNamedServer& operator+=(const T& request) {
 if(numRequests()>=maxLimit) {
   throw OverLimit();
}
else {
 requests.push_back(request);
}
 return *this;
}
};
```

Now, the problem is as follows:

> Let `s1`,`s2` and `s3` be three objects from the class `LimitedNamedServer`. Why will the following code not compile, how can this problem be fixed:

```
s1=s2+s3
```

I have no idea why this is not supposed to compile. From what I know the `+` operator I defined for the class `Server` can also be used on objects from the class `LimitedNamedServer`. My best guess is that it happens due to that inside the implementation of `+`, I create a new Server but not a `LimitedNamedServer`, and that the error occurs because `s1` expects to recieve a `LimitedNamedServer` object while this is not the object returned.

This is just a guess however, can someone please explain the reason for that?

Comment: What exactly is the error? And please format your code.

Comment: Lets start with the error

Comment: I wrote that this is a question from a written exam, I did not run the code myself.

Comment: One thing is that `LimitedNamedServer` is missing `class` keyword, but really, the easiest way would be to actually compile it and check the real errors.

Comment: Can you indent your code properly please so that we can read it?

Comment: Just compile it and you'll see immediately what the problem is. You'll need to actually finish the program first, though, because loads of code is missing here.

Comment: @איתן לוי The first step then would be to run it to produce an error. Trying to guess isn't a good use of time.

Comment: Why do you think your guess is wrong?

Comment: As you already know, your operator + returns a `Server` and not a `LimitedNamedServer`. You probably want to define an operator plus that use and returns `LimitedNamedServer` as `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are of that type.

Comment: Should we assume that somehow poltergeists stole the `class` that should be between `template<class T>` and `LimitedNameServer` at the very top of the second paste ?

Comment: @איתןלוי I would point out that this is a question from a written exam. Once the exam is over, the natural thing (for me, at least) would be to feed the code to a compiler. The compiler would tell me why that line does not compile, and this answer would be faster than any other resource. (If the compiler's error message is tough to understand, then that could be a question to ask here. But start with the source; ask the compiler why it does not like that line.)

Comment: I wonder, if all the downvoters understand the question and have an answer. It is not so easy. Besides the incomplete code (which I completed in 5 minutes) and some errors, including lookup rules for in/dependent names and missing virtual qualifier and others. The basic problem is that the operator + in the class needs only one parameter and using that operator a Type Server will be returned by the operator +, and there is no assignement to the derived class possible. Only Phil1970 understood the problem . . .   +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to explain to yourself why it should compile instead…

Given that `operator +` works with `Server` ask yourself what would happen to `name` and `maxLimit` if that code would be allowed to compile.

Hint: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Thus as you already know, you need to defined an `operator +` for `LimitedNamedServer` too. Typical implementation would be:

```
template <class T>
LimitedNamedServer<T> operator+(const LimitedNamedServer<T> &lhs, const LimitedNamedServer<T> &rhs)
{
    LimitedNamedServer result = lhs;
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}
```

Written that way, you reuse existing code and don't need to give friendship.

Comment: This can be further enhanced by making the first argument by-value rather than const-reference and removing `result` entirely. The resulting code then just becomes `lhs += rhs; return lhs;`